# Illegal characters in path fix?

Tags: mule

I have a https:outbound-endpoint and I am trying to set the path in AnypointStudio but It doesn't allow me to set the full path due to illegal characters being used for username and password. I want to post to an endpoint and have the http.request includes the full url

eg. my path is this URL `https://http.testserver1.host.com:9126/TestAttempt?Username=Admin$$1&Password=0de5z_Wdfjf$54!&Content=te`

I have tried using setting the user, pass and content in a message-properties-transformer like this

```
 <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" doc:name="HTTPS" host="http.testserver1.host.com" port="9126" path="TestAttempt" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS">
             <message-properties-transformer> 
                <add-message-property key="Username" value="Admin$$1"/>
                <add-message-property key="Password" value="0de5z_Wdfjf$54!"/>
                <add-message-property key="Content" value="test"/>
             </message-properties-transformer>
```

but it can't seem to pick up the user and pass.

Is there a work around or how can i acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just put `<message-properties-transformer>` before `<https:outbound-endpoint ...`.

By doing it I can pick up the username and password correctly, although they contain illegal characters. Following is my Flows example, it works for both HTTP and HTTPS:

```
<flow name="senderFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" path="/escape" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTPS"/>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="Username" value="Admin$$1"/>
        <add-message-property key="Password" value="0de5z_Wdfjf$54!"/>
        <add-message-property key="Content" value="test"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration1" path="/escape" method="POST" doc:name="HTTPS"/>
</flow>
<flow name="receiverFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" path="/escape" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTPS"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Notes: for HTTPS you have to configure the TLS/SSL.

I add another example which written using Mule 3.5 (using http:outbound-endpoint) and it's working properly.

```
<flow name="senderFlow" doc:name="senderFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="escape" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="Username" value="Admin$$1"/>
        <add-message-property key="Password" value="0de5z_Wdfjf$54!"/>
        <add-message-property key="Content" value="test"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8083" path="escape" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
<flow name="receiverFlow" doc:name="receiverFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8083" path="escape" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Won't work for me when using <https:outbound-endpoint> I see you are using <http:listener>

Comment: Please try the new example. It's working properly: username and password are passed to the receiverFlow.

Comment: This does not work for me. I am using Mule 3.2.1 maybe that is the issue

Comment: Your also missing closing tags on your inbound and outbound endpoints.

Comment: It looks like markdown incorrectly translate my code (it's shown incompletely). I open this post in two different browsers with different appearance.
My code is shown properly when I edit it. You might get the complete code by clicking "improve this answer"

Comment: I clicked edit and looked at the code, it still doesn't work for me, having the <message-properties-transformer> inside or outside the <https:outbound-endpoint does not work.